# What is the code inside a paginator view?(Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-4

```
<?php echo $users->links('view.name'); ?>
```

If I specify this view in laravel-4, what will be the code inside it? I can't find an example in the docs. Any example please?

according to this http://laravel.com/docs/pagination

Answer (score 0):

If you use the paginator like this

```
<?php echo $users->links(); ?>
```

Laravel will use the default view which is defined inside **app/config/view.php** as

```
'pagination' => 'pagination::slider-3',
```

With this default option, your pagination will use the Illuminate/Pagination/views/slider-3.php view,

which is the following:

```
<?php if ($paginator->getLastPage() > 1): ?>

  <ul class="pagination">

    <?php echo $presenter->render(); ?>

  </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

You can define your own view, and then use inside it the $paginator object to format it according to your needs.

You can see an example [here](http://www.codingswag.com/2013/11/custom-pagination-in-laravel-4/).